# VBA - Keep formatting when replacing formula with its value

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on a macro to replace the formulas in a filtered range with the values. While I have managed to make it work with using areas instead of array (this is still a WIP and is a different issue entirely), I can't seem to figure out a way to keep it as text if the value of my UDF is text and let it be a number if it is in fact a number.

[image: 10 cells in]

The first 5 rows have been iterated through those two columns (the filter is on a different column)
As you can see, the value of my UDF is supposed to be "000691" but when replacing the formula with the value, it gets rid of the leading 0s because of it going from text to number. I was checking the Numberformat but of course that's set to Standard since I want the value of the UDF, not `=SDEFAULT(B209)`.. The UDF is a simply index/match result from a datasheet my colleagues and I need to use a bunch.

My Code:

```vb
Sub ReplaceFilteredListFormulasWithValuesUsingArray()
'
' ReplaceFilteredListFormulasWithValuesUsingArray Macro
'
' Hotkey: Ctrl+Shift+M
'
    ' Declare variables
    Dim filteredRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim area As Range
    
    ' Define the filtered range as the visible cells in the selection
    Set filteredRange = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        
    ' Loop through each area in the visible range and load its values into the values array
    For Each area In filteredRange.Areas
        'For Each cell In area
        '    Debug.Print cell.Value
        'Next cell
        area.Value = area.Value
    Next area
End Sub
```

When I use the excel copy Paste as Values option, it doesn't get rid of the formatting of the cell (text remains text). However, you can't use that in a filtered range. I could use `area.copy` with `area.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` but so many uses of copy paste would slow the whole thing down to which point I'd be better off unfiltering and copy pasting as values by hand (untested but I'm trying to get my point across and work without the clipboard).

`.Value2` gives me the same result as `.Value` and `.Text` just gives me "Object required" error since area.Text is Null. Using `'` is also not an option (I think) since most of the UDF's do give back a number as seen in column X.

Hope my question is clear and someone can help, thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Someone hastily deleted their message about using `.Value(11)` instead of `.Value` and this has kept the leading 0's as intended but removed the conditional formatting that was on the cells. If that's the only downside, I can live with it. My code on sheets usually doesn't check for conditional formatting anyway.

Comment: It was my hasty deletion of which you speak - I deleted because of the inconsistent results when the source cell contains a calculation, e.g. `Value(11)` of a cell containing `=PRODUCT(10,10)` replicates the formula in full, but `Value(11)` of a cell containing `=10*A1` (where A1 contains 10) yields the constant `100`, so the 'values effect'  of `PasteSpecial -> as Values` is not at all a 'given'

Comment: Editing your own answers/questions seems to be a real issue the last couple of days.. The Value(11) method also takes *forever*, even when iterating through the code step by step, it lags the hell out of everything in my Excel. The normal `.Value = .Value` is fine and the unfiltered way went fine as well. I even tested it in a new unformatted sheet with only the first 8 columns of my original datasheet and it froze :/

Comment: Re-reading your question, specifically your objective, I think you could be more specific in the value you assign to `filteredRange`, i.e. `Set filteredRange = Application.Intersect(Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23))` since only the 'visible' formulas are what you seem to want to target

Comment: Usually it's everything in the selected range that contains a formula I want to get rid of without having to unfilter-refilter everything. So yours and mine would be the same then, no? I don't understand why it (.Value(11)) lags so several compared to its twin (.Value)

Comment: My syntax would skip any cells containing a constant (even if there aren't many) - if your formula exists only to provide the leading 0s then why not just use a custom # format e.g. `000000` ? If you `Debug.Print` the `Value(11)` for an emtpy cell, you will see that it comes to 28 rows vs only 1 for the `Value` - so it does actually contain significantly more information

Comment: Some of my UDF's are supposed to give back text (or numbers formatted as text like `000691` but others can provide back actual numbers like prices. So I can't just format it as such. Would it maybe be an idea to check prior to setting the values the whole range for if the cell contains leading 0's but no decimal separator and union it together, setting the formatting of that range to `000000`, and then setting the values with just `.Value` ? I'll test it out when I get some time and get back to you on that. Also gonna see what this 28 rows shenanigans is about on an empty cell õ.o